# Is there a way to put "QByteArray" variable data directly into "int" variable without casting?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

The conversion you're trying to do is not just converting the QByteArray data to an int.
For example, assuming that QByteArray a [3] contains [0] = 36, [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aChFC.png) = 23, and [2] = 12 data, use the b variable in the form of int b in the form b = 362312. I want to do it.

In order to use QByteArray data as int data, QByteArray variable is assigned to QString variable and cast to string variable.
And I tried to print out the string variable, but the strange unknown data is output.

I tried to cast a string using toInt () after confirming that the string is printed normally, but the string is printed as strange characters.
So I could not do toInt ().

I run a lot of tests and the code is messy.
The reason I didn't delete the comment was not to show that I've tried various things.

```
 if (QCanBus::instance()->plugins().contains(QStringLiteral("socketcan"))) {
            qWarning() << "plugin available";
        }

        QString errorString;
        QCanBusDevice *device = QCanBus::instance()->createDevice(
            QStringLiteral("socketcan"), QStringLiteral("vcan0"), &errorString);
        if (!device) {
            qWarning() << errorString;
        } else {
            device->connectDevice();
            std::cout << "connected vcan0" << std::endl;

            device->connect(device, &QCanBusDevice::framesReceived, [this, device]() {

            QCanBusFrame frame = device->readFrame();
            QString testV = frame.toString();
//            int testI = testV.split(" ")[0].toInt();

            QString qvSpeed = frame.payload();
//            int a = frame.payload().length();

            std::string text = testV.toUtf8().constData();
            std::string vSpeed = qvSpeed.toLocal8Bit().constData();

            //At that point the vVal values ​​are being updated in real time.
            //I want to pass the updated vVal to qml gui in real time.
//            int vVal = static_cast<int>(frame.payload()[0]);


//            for(int i = 0; i < frame.payload().length(); ++i)
//                std::cout << std::hex << static_cast<int>(frame.payload()[i]);

//            std::cout << std::endl;


//            if(vVal)
//            int tSpeed = static_cast<int>(frame.payload()[0]);
//            std::stringstream stream;
//            stream <<

            testVal1 += 0;

//            if(frame.frameId() == 001)
//                testVal2 = static_cast<int>(frame.payload()[0]);

//            testVal2 += 20;

//            duration += 200;
//            emit sendMessage(testVal1, testVal2);

            std::cout << vSpeed << std::endl;


//            if(frame.frameId() == 001)
//                std::cout << testI << std::endl;

//            std::cout << "--------------" << std::hex << static_cast<int>(frame.payload()[0]) << "----------------" << std::endl;
            });
        }
```

Finally, QByteArray a [3] = {32, 34, 12};
Assuming you have data, you want to use this like int b = 323412.
In order to do that, I thought it would convert to a string and then to an integer, but even strings are not normal output.

I'm also attaching the strange string that is currently printed out below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aChFC.png)

Comment: You seem to be confused about what `QByteArray` actually provides, what a string is, and how integers are represented in a computer.  If you wish to build a base-10 number out of these values, you could do this: `int b = ((int)a[0] * 10 + (int)a[1]) * 10 + (int)a[2];`

Comment: I have no idea what your question is.  You really, really, need to do better at creating a [mvce].  For starters, QCanBus has nothing to do with your question.  Use something like `QByteArray data = {36, 23, 1};` and work from there.

Answer (score 1):

Since `QByteArray` stores its data as `char *` you can just cast its internal data, for example:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    uint32_t num = 1234;

    std::cout << "original number:" << num << std::endl;

    std::cout << "bytes: " << std::endl;
    QByteArray arr(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&num), sizeof(uint32_t));
    for(int i = 0;i < arr.size();i ++)
    {
        std::cout << "  0x" << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << (arr.at(i) & 0xFF) << std::endl;
    }

    uint32_t *num2 = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t *>(arr.data());

    std::cout << "casted number :" << std::dec << *num2 << std::endl;

    return a.exec();
}
```

But I would not recommend this 'C' approach since it is fraught with errors.
Btw, I've never seen CAN data converted to QString. Usually it just 8 bytes of data, you worth cast it to a data struct instead, for example:

```
struct Data
{
    uint32_t value1;
    uint32_t value2;

} inData, outData;


inData.value1 = 1234;
inData.value2 = 5678;

QByteArray arr(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&inData), sizeof(Data));

outData = *reinterpret_cast<Data *>(arr.data());
//memcpy(&outData, arr.data(), static_cast<size_t>(arr.size())); // or this
```